# 'Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for' runtime error when upgrading from Angular 4 to 5.0.1

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, angular5

This is fine in Angular 4.x, just not Angular 5.0.1.  This project was generated with Angular CLI.

```
compiler.js:466 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RegistrationService: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:466)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15546)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15381)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15361)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15721)
    at eval (compiler.js:15632)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15592)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15160)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (compiler.js:14998)
syntaxError @ compiler.js:466
CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata @ compiler.js:15546
CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata @ compiler.js:15381
CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata @ compiler.js:15361
CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata @ compiler.js:15721
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:15632
CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata @ compiler.js:15592
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:15160
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary @ compiler.js:14998
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:15086
CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata @ compiler.js:15071
JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:33486
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:33447
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:33363
CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:230
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5446
(anonymous) @ main.ts:12
../../../../../src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:640
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
1 @ main.bundle.js:670
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
```

This is what the constructor looks like:

```
     constructor(
    private apiHelperService: ApiHelperService
  ) {
  }
```

The class has @Injectable()

```
    @Injectable()
export class ApiHelperService {
```

It has also properly imported into the module providers.

```
providers: [
    AuthGuard,
    ApiHelperService,
```

If I change it to this, then the error goes away and it works, but then it wants you to change every constructor in the entire solution to this syntax, which I don't believe to be correct.

```
@Inject(ApiHelperService) private apiHelperService: ApiHelperService
```

Here is my tsconfig.json, which does have emitDecoratorMetadata properly set to true

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you import one service to another? How do you do it? Do you use one index.ts file?

Comment: I use on index.html file and yes, I do import service into other services.  For example:    constructor(private http: Http,
    @Inject(LOCALE_ID) protected localeId: string,
    private appInsightsService: AppInsightsService,
    private apiHelperService: ApiHelperService) {
   }

Comment: I asked cause I had similar issue. I had services directory with index.ts file. This file looks like this -> export * from './employee.service';  export * from './member.service';

Comment: And I imported my services like this -> import { EmployeeService, MemberService } from './service';

Comment: But when I change path like this -> import { EmployeeService } from './service/employee.service'; It solved my issue

Comment: no imports in my index file

Comment: import { ApiHelperService } from 'app/services/api-helper.service';

Comment: Well.. I don't know.. Do you have any errors in your editor?

Comment: compile time, zero errors.  Its happy.  Its only run time.

Comment: I mean go to your RegistrationService.ts file and look at all your code there. Visual Studio Code highlights this issues for example.

Comment: I did that as well, no issues noted.  VSCode intellisense working fine as well.

Comment: i just downgraded to angular 4.4.6 and everything works fine again.  sigh.

Comment: Perfect! It is a bug. You can remove your question

Comment: i'm not 100% sure its a bug though...it might be some setting/config/pattern that must change when going to Ang5 that maybe isn't documented.

Comment: this is working 100% correct in my project. 

`export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  constructor(private apiHelperService: ApiHelperService){
  }
}
`
Can you please share the RegistrationService code also. May be something is missing there......

Comment: FYI, the latest Angular 5.1 works fine now.  I was able to upgrade and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [Angular 5 Update blog post](https://blog.angular.io/version-5-0-0-of-angular-now-available-37e414935ced) the author mentions that they are using a static injector instead of a reflection based one and mentions that the reflection polyfills are no longer needed but in my case it was.

If you removed the polyfills for reflections try adding them again:

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

I hope it woks for you as well.

Comment: I played with these as well.  Interestingly, when I commented the first one out, I would get the error:  Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation  but when it was there, i would get the more specific error.

Comment: Angular has released a new version https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#bug-fixes-1 with a fix for "compiler: recognize NgModule with a redundant Injectable (#20320) (4cc6abb)". That might be it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, for Angular 6.1 migration, it was a missing:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import "zone.js";
```

inside the `boot`file.

Answer (score -1):

The error mentions that you're using a wron constructor for RegistrationService.

Comment: was this meant to be an answer?