# Can't resolve all parameters fixed using @Injectable AND @Inject?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, angular5

I've been slowly upgrading to Angular 5. However, a few days ago I started seeing this error from my ApiService:
[can't resolve all parameters for ApiService(?)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9R6PO.png)

**This only started happening after I added new components** (none of which actually use the service in question). Before then, ApiService was working totally fine. My ApiService looks something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
...
@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient)
}
...
```

My tsconfig.json already has 'emitDecoratorMetadata' set to true. My app.module.ts has ApiService as a provider and imported properly.

However, if I use both @Injectable AND @Inject then it's much happier and compiles properly (I was doing this as a test to see why it was breaking; I know this is something you shouldn't need to do).

Is there another configuration that I might be forgetting? Most of the answers I've found so far have said to include @Injectable() include, emitDecoratorMetadata, or put the service as part of the app.module.ts providers, all of which I've done. Again, ApiService had been working up until I started adding more components.

I'm using webpack-dev-server to run my server. If I use 'ng serve' it works totally fine, which leads me to believe that it might be something wrong in how I'm configuring webpack-dev-server? Was there recently an update that may need me to change my configurations around a little bit?

Thanks for any advice and help!

Comment: A way to replicate the problem would be helpful - a repo, https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular , etc.

Comment: @estus Sorry for the late reply. I've been trying to replicate the problem with a new project, but to no avail. I'll keep trying. In the meantime, should I be looking out for anything in particular? Is webpack known to play a part in errors like this? I'm wondering if something happened such that I messed up my webpack config. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @estus I've found the solution! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313571/uncaught-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-runtime-error-when-upgrading

Comment: It makes sense. Previously missing Reflect polyfill would throw an explicit error. I guess it's not thrown in 5 because Reflect is optional with AOT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! ['Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for' runtime error when upgrading from Angular 4 to 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313571/uncaught-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-runtime-error-when-upgrading)

It seems that I just needed to add

```
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

to my polyfills.ts. This seems to be a problem specific to upgrading to Angular 5. I hope this helps out anyone else who's had a similar problem!