# Angular cant inject HttpClient getting 'Can't resolve all parameters for CustomerService' error

Tags: typescript, angular2-routing, injectable

I have a `customerService` where im trying to inject `httpClient`. Error is happening on the line where i commented `//error happens on this line`. Everything works until i try to inject httpClient into my service.

Error message is :

```
`compiler.js:485 Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for CustomerService: (?).
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15700)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15535)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15515)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15875)
    at compiler.js:15786
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15746)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15314)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary
```

(compiler.js:15133)`

Not sure where to start debugging this. any help would be appreciated. thank you!

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {

    private baseUri: string = "hosthere.com"

    constructor(
        private http: HttpClient //error happens on this line
    ) { }

    get(email: string): Observable<any> {
        const uri = `${this.baseUri}/customer/${email}`;
        return this.http.get(uri).map(res => res.json());
    }
}
```

Here is my Customer Module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { SharedModule } from "../../shared/shared.module";

import { CustomerRouteModule } from "./cutomer.route.module";

import { SearchComponent } from "./";

import { CustomerService } from "../../services";


    @NgModule({
        imports: [SharedModule, CustomerRouteModule],
        declarations: [SearchComponent],
        providers: [CustomerService],
        exports: []
    })
    export class CustomerModule {

    }
```

Here is my shared module

```
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule  } from "@angular/common/http";
import { AppMaterialModule } from "./app.material.module";
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";

import { HttpClientProvider } from "../services";


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        HttpClientModule ,
        AppMaterialModule
    ],
    providers: [

    ],
    exports: [
        AppMaterialModule,
        FlexLayoutModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpClientModule 
    ]
})
export class SharedModule {

}
```

Comment: can you also provide how you use the customer service?

Comment: @brijmcq im not even using this anywhere. my application simply dying. no errors in compiler though.

Comment: have you tried restarting ng serve?

Comment: @brijmcq im using webpack for this application.

Comment: then try to restart your webpack server, errors like this could come from anywhere

Comment: @brijmcq i have already done that. i also made sure i have `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,` in my `tsconfig.json` file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165801/discussion-between-brijmcq-and-kkdeveloper7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an answer here:

['Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for' runtime error when upgrading from Angular 4 to 5.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313571/uncaught-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-runtime-error-when-upgrading)

I removed reflection from my polyfills, silly me.

Thank you all for help.

Answer (score 1):

You probably followed an old guide/tutorial for http.

When using `HttpClient`, you need to provide the type you want to return, in effect, you don't need to `.map` the data making your code somewhat shorter.

```
get(email: string): Observable<any> {
        const uri = `${this.baseUri}/customer/${email}`;
            //add your model here something like 
            //return this.http.get<Customer>(uri);
        return this.http.get<any>(uri);
    }
```

Note that you don't need to provide a type if you provide a response type. Here's a code snippet taken from official [doc](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)

```
getTextFile(filename: string) {
  // The Observable returned by get() is of type Observable<string>
  // because a text response was specified.
  // There's no need to pass a <string> type parameter to get().
  return this.http.get(filename, {responseType: 'text'})
    .pipe(
      tap( // Log the result or error
        data => this.log(filename, data),
        error => this.logError(filename, error)
      )
    );
}
```

Comment: per your suggestion i added a return type of any to a  get 
`return this.http.get<any>(uri);` 
experiencing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create new file or add to exists **polyfills.ts**

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

include to webpack.config

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: 'source-map',
    entry: {
        'app': './ClientApp/main.ts',
        'polyfills': './ClientApp/polyfills.ts'
    },...
```

**it's help for me**