# Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Location: (?) in angular7 webpack app

Tags: angular, webpack, angular6, webpack-4, angular7

I get the following error in my browser when running locally a node.js-angular7-webpack4.21 app that I created NOT using angular-cli:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for Location: (?).
```

I have extensively researched the issue. First, I do not have any component, service or other named 'Location', so I have no idea the parameters of what entity the compiler is having a hard time resolving. Second, I have only 4 services in my entire app, none of which point at each other so this is not a circular dependency issue. Neither did I forget to put the '@Injectable()' decorator correctly in either service file. Really, after triple and octuple checking, this is not the issue.

Moreover, I have reproduced this issue with an empty angular6 project consisting of 0 services and only 1 component with just words inside a div in its template, in which case I get the same error only about 'ApplicationModule' instead of 'Location'. So even though I do not have webpack errors, I assume the problem is in my webpack configuration, hence I will put bellow the webpack.config.js and tsconfig.js files, and hopefully someone can find something extremely stupid about them.

Here is my tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": ["dom", "es2017", "es5", "es6", "es7"],
  "outDir": "dist",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "removeComments": true,
  "noImplicitAny": false,
  "typeRoots": ["types"],
  "types": ["node"]
},
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

And here is my webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const path = require('path'); // needed ?

module.exports = {

    mode: 'development',

    devtool: 'source-map',

    entry: {
        'main': helpers.root('app/main.ts'),
        'vendor': helpers.root('vendor.ts'),
        'polyfills': helpers.root('polyfills.ts')
    },

    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: '[name].js'
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: {
                        configFileName: helpers.root('tsconfig.json')
                    }
                }, 'angular2-template-loader?keepUrl=true']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    // 'style-loader',
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // 'to-string-loader',
                    'css-loader'
                ],
                exclude: [helpers.root('stylesheets')]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: 'raw-loader',
                include: [helpers.root('stylesheets')]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html'
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
            // both options are optional
            filename: "[name].css",
            chunkFilename: "main.css"
        }),
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            // For Angular 5, see also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20357#issuecomment-343683491
            /\@angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)fesm5/,
            helpers.root('app'), // location of your src
            {
                // your Angular Async Route paths relative to this root drectory
            }
        )
    ]

};
```

Thank you guys.

Comment: I have the same issue after updating Angular from `6.03` to `6.1.10` version. Did you have any luck fixing it?

Comment: No, I ended up switching to @ngtools/webpack as a typescript loader, which doesn't require the angular2-template-loader and gives better error messages when building. So it made me change a few things and now everything works, but I don't know if the things I changed where the ones problematic with the old configuration, sorry :(

Comment: However, @TomasPetovsky, two of the things I "fixed" that could be relevant to your case: In main.ts I changed const platform = platformBrowserDynamic; platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule); to just platformBrowserDynamic.bootstrapModule(AppModule); - no idea why this works, but I've seen other people mention this too. Second thing was to make sure my main.ts is the last entry in the webpack config, because the HtmlWebpackPlugin apparently injects links to the main html in order of appearance, so dependencies of main.js are being loaded after it (also weird).

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue when upgrade angular `6.1.10` to `7.0.6` and webpack `4.19.1`.
I did some changes described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47313571/uncaught-error-cant-resolve-all-parameters-for-runtime-error-when-upgrading/47327208#47327208) answer and it worked. To short:

Add to your `polyfill.ts`

```
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove or upgrade the `reflect-metadata` from the package.json

In my case I removed it from the file and reinstalled the nodes modules from scratch. Note that to prevent conflicting modules artefacts you might have to remove `package.json.lock` as well

```sh
rimraf node_modules
npm i
```